# I want to find the closest td when button in that tr is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

The problem is that even if 2nd button is clicked, it is finding first credentials only. So I want that if I click on the second button, it should give me that button's closest td with username and password

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jsLoginButton").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      //Get login details
      configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_ID = $('.loginID').closest('td').filter(':first').text();
      configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_PASSWORD = $('.loginPassword').closest('td').filter(':first').text();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="padding: 3px">Username</th>
      <th style="padding: 3px">Password</th>
      <th style="padding: 3px">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginID">abc.user1@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginPassword">Asdf1234!</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">
      <button class="jsLoginButton">login</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginID">xyz@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginPassword">Asdf1234!</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">
      <button class="jsLoginButton">login</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/parag_bandewar/c8w73rup/

Comment: Which td you want?

Comment: Closest one after or before?

Comment: If I click on 2nd login button, it should select xyz@gmail.com and not abc.user1@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using a class selector to find all the `.loginID` and `.loginPassword` elements.

Instead you can fix the logic by using the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the event. From there you can use `closest('tr')` to get the row, and `find()` to select the required elements. Also note that you don't need the `each()` call. You can apply `click()` directly to the collection of all `.jsLoginButton` elements. Try this:

```js
var configuration = {
  loginPage: {}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jsLoginButton").click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_ID = $tr.find('.loginID').text();
    configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_PASSWORD = $tr.find('.loginPassword').text()

    console.log(configuration);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="padding: 3px">Username</th>
      <th style="padding: 3px">Password</th>
      <th style="padding: 3px">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginID">abc.user1@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginPassword">Asdf1234!</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">
      <button class="jsLoginButton">login</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginID">xyz@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px" class="loginPassword">Asdf1234!</td>
    <td style="padding: 3px">
      <button class="jsLoginButton">login</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` to get the `tr`, from there use `find` to get the `td` you want. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".jsLoginButton").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      //Get login details
      configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_ID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.loginID').text();
      configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_PASSWORD = $(this).closest('tr').find('.loginPassword').text();

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jsLoginButton").click(function() {
        configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_ID = $(this).closest('td').siblings('.loginID').text();
        configuration.loginPage.LOGIN_PASSWORD =$(this).closest('td').siblings('.loginPassword').text();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="padding:3px">Username</th>
      <th style="padding:3px">Password</th>
      <th style="padding:3px">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:3px" class="loginID">abc.user1@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding:3px" class="loginPassword">Asdf1234!</td>
    <td style="padding:3px">
      <button class="jsLoginButton">login</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:3px" class="loginID">xyz@gmail.com</td>
    <td style="padding:3px" class="loginPassword">Asdf1234!</td>
    <td style="padding:3px">
      <button class="jsLoginButton">login</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```